# Locus of vertex

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

A variable parabola of latus rectum $l $, touches a fixed equal parabola , the axes of the two curves being parallel . Then locus of the vertex of  the moving curve is a parabola , then what is the latus rectum of this curve .

I took the fixed curve as $y^2 =4bx$

And the variable curve is $(y-k)^2 = 4a(x-h)$

Where $(h,k)$ is the vertex . But now how to proceed ?

Comment: Let me try to get this straight: the latus rectum of the first parabola is given and remains constant, while the parabola itself moves in such a way that its orientation remains the same but its point of contact to the second moves, right? And is the latus rectum of the first equal to that of the second, or independent? In the latter case, do you know the shape of both? Or looking at your formulas, would it be correct to take $a,b$ as given but $h,k$ as depending on the point of contact, so that you are looking for a relation between $h$ and $k$? Btw: there is no $k$ in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like projective geometry, so I'll be explaining using terms from there. Your first parabola [can be written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) as

$$(x,y,1)\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&0&2b\\0&-1&0\\2b&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Its axis is the $x$ axis, evidenced by the fact that $(1,0,0)$ is the only point at infinity (i.e. last coordinate zero) which lies on that conic as well. Now I'd like to describe the tangent for a given direction. A direction can be described by a point at infinity. I'll use the point $(t,1,0)$ with parameter $t$. For $t\in\mathbb R$ this can describe any direction except horizontal, which is just fine since that parabola can't have a horizontal tangent in any case.

So we need the tangent through a given point. One way to compute that is by computing the polar line of that point. It will intersect the conic in the two contact points. Usually that leads to two tangents, but in our case, with the point chosen at infinity, one of the tangents will be the line at infinity, so we can pick the remaining (finite) contact point.

To compute a polar line, multiply the point with the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&2b\\0&-1&0\\2b&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\cdot\begin{pmatrix}t\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\2bt\end{pmatrix}$$

This is the line $y=2bt$. It intersects the conic at $x=\frac{y^2}{4b}=bt^2$. So $(bt^2,2bt)$ is the point with the given tangent direction. Now do the same for the second curve with $a$ instead of $b$. Setting the point of contact equal, you get

\begin{align*}
bt^2 &= at^2+h \\
2bt &= 2at+k
\end{align*}

You can eliminate the variable $t$ from this, e.g. using the resultant computed using the Sylvester matrix

$$0=\begin{vmatrix}
a-b & 0 & h \\
2(a-b) & k & 0 \\
0 & 2(a-b) & k
\end{vmatrix}=(a-b)(k^2 + 4ah - 4bh)$$

So the equation of the locus of the vertex is

$$k^2 = 4(b-a)h$$